# merging time series datasets, but missing the time series column

Tags: r

I've tried methods from others for merging time series datasets. However, The time series column is missing. Please see captured screen.

[image]

Here is the example of my datasets.

```
df1 = data.frame(Time = round(seq(1, 200, length.out= 50)), Var1 = runif(50,1, 10))
df2 = data.frame(Time = round(seq(1, 200, length.out= 80)), Var2 = runif(80,1, 10))
df3 = data.frame(Time = round(seq(1, 200, length.out= 100)), Var3 = runif(100,1, 10))
```

Here is what I've tried.

```
a = read.zoo(df1,drop = FALSE)
b = read.zoo(df2,drop = FALSE)
c = read.zoo(df3,drop = FALSE)
abc = merge(a, b, c)
```

How can I add one first column listing the Time? Any comments about this task that I can learn from you?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This converts all three data frames to zoo and merges them into a combined zoo object.

```
z <- do.call("merge", lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), read.zoo, drop = FALSE))
```

Note that in zoo objects the time is stored in the index attribute. It is *not* a column.  The statement shown above already includes the time as derived from the first columns of each of the data frames.

Comment: How can I add one column that lists the time to the merged dataset?

Comment: You don't need to add it.  It already took the times from the first columns of the data frames.  If you want to change the times and not use the times that  the data frames already specified then `time(z) <- ...whatever...`

Comment: I want to calculate the bin average including the time. So, I need to put the time back in. Can you show to how to put the time column back?

Comment: `cbind(z, time = time(z))[, c(4, 1:3)]`  You can omit the [...] part if it is ok that the time be in the last column rather than the first.  Note that the zoo object needs to be the first argument.

Comment: Thanks! Just FYI. I learn some techniques from this post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/merging-multiple-data-files-into-one-data-frame/ This method works, too.

Comment: That is unnecessary here since zoo supports n-way merges in contrast to R's merge.data.frame discussed there which only supports 2-way merges.